# Who is performing the music played on the loudspeakers at Santuario del Cerro San Cristobal, Santiago, Chile?

Tags: music, santiago-de-chile

I walked up to the statue of the Immaculate Conception today. Around the area are loudspeakers playing pre-recorded music of a woman singing, accompanied by what sounds to me like a single guitar. I noted down some of the words and having done some web searches, I believe one of the songs I heard was "Milagro de amor", but it looks as though this has been performed by many different people. I'd like to know who is performing the version being played there and where I can get hold of a copy. Thanks!

Comment: you can use Shazam on a cell phone to identify it exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be surprised if it changes over time, but one seems to be the album " Mi mas caro amor " by Hermanos Romero Alejandro & Rodolfo Fuentes Rivera (Cerro San Cristobal).

Link to album on Amazon: https://www.amazon.es/Cerro-San-Cristobal/dp/B07588VMCV